# Find the number of elements in a list

Tags: r, list, count

I am working with a data set that has a column which I have turned into a list that looks like this:

```
[[997]]
[1] NA

[[998]]
[1] "0.99"  " 0.99" " 0.99" " 0.99" " 0.99" " 2.99"

[[999]]
[1] "19.99"  " 9.99"  " 4.99"  " 79.99" " 15.99" " 14.99" " 99.99" " 7.99" 
[9] " 59.99" " 49.99"

[[1000]]
[1] NA
```

I need to count how many components are in each element of a list and save these values in a matrix. For example, in 999 the output should be 10 and in 1000 the output should be 0. Can anyone suggest a function that could help? Thank you.

Comment: BTW, your title does not reflect your question. You are not counting for character, you want to count for number of elements in a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, using a small example of list `v`:

```r
v = vector("list",4)
v[[1]] = 1:5
v[[2]] = 1:50
v[[3]] = NA
```

```r
> v
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[[2]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
[37] 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50

[[3]]
[1] NA

[[4]]
NULL
```

And you get the count by doing:

```r
l = unlist(lapply(v,length))
```

and

```r
> l
[1]  5 50  1  0
```

If you don't want to count for NA

```r
l = unlist(lapply(v,function(x)length(x[!is.na(x)])))
```

and you get:

```r
> l
[1]  5 50  0  0
```

**EDIT: from @markus and @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 comments**

As mentioned by @markus, you can go much much simpler by doing:

```r
> lengths(v)
[1]  5 50  1  0
```

And as mentioned by @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1, you can get rid of NA count by doing:

```r
> replace(lengths(v), is.na(v), 0)
[1]  5 50  0  0
```

Comment: Great, Thank you! I was struggling with not counting for NA's. This was very helpful!

Comment: Better use `lengths(v)`

Comment: OMG !! I didn't know about this function ! Thank you @markus. I will edit my answer to add it.

Comment: as pointed out by @user20650, how you get rid of the count for NA ?

Comment: @dc37, `replace(lengths(v), is.na(v), 0)`.

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1, thanks I'm editing my answer

Answer (score 2):

Additional to the existing solution by [@dc37](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59129884/12158757), you can also use the following with `lengths()`

```
lengths(v)
```

**If you don't want to take `NA` into account, then try**

```
lengths(v)*!is.na(v)
```

Comment: but this gives a length of one for the NA values

Comment: @user20650 thanks, please see my updated solution

Comment: thanks, I dont think that will work **if** the aim is to count the non NA elements. Try using dc's example but with `v[[1]] = c(1:5, NA)`

Comment: @user20650, I think the OP needs to clarify what they would want in that case.

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 ; yes fair point

Comment: @user20650, in this particular case of mix NAs and elements, the `unlist(lapply(v,function(x)length(x[!is.na(x)])))` will work

Comment: @user20650 well....`rapply` does not work,  but `lengths` is still available. I am using dc's example